# extract partial text with innertext using Simple HTML dom parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

i am **scraping** an address from a span, the format of address is
house_no address
 landmark 
 city

i want to extract house number,landmark & city and store them in separate variable

example of address:

```
123, cool area <br> famous hospital<br>city
```

my code sould extract & store values like:

```
$variable1="123, cool area"
$variable2="famous hospital"
$variable3="city"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply split the text along the `<br>` tags using

```
$parts = explode("<br>", $fullAddress);
```

You may then be better off to trim the results to remove excess spaces...

```
$parts = array_map('trim', $parts);
```